# How to show a welcome screen at startup if no document is open when app starts?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Xcode has a really nice screen that shows up when you first start it; it shows your recent projects along with resources for you, but it only shows up if you didn't have a document open when you started it. I'd like to a similar (albeit less complicated) welcome screen. I already have it designed and in a .nib file, but I'd to know how I'd code it to come up when the user opens the application without there having been a previously opened document.

Here is the screen I'm referring to (showing my recent projects):

[image: Xcode start screen]

Comment: I would also love to have a definitive, post-Lion compatible, best-practice answer to this common behavior. NSApplicationDelegate is so complicated already, and then you have "resume", automatic termination, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that OS X's `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` works the same way as in iOS, in which case you could do something like:

```
if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"opened"]) {
   //load your special view here; no documents have been opened;
}
else {
   //open up some previously opened document.
}
```

When a document is opened up, you can just do something like:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"" forKey:@"opened"]; //doesn't matter what you set as long as something is set.
```

Then if you ever want to reset it (ex if all documents are closed) you can just do:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"opened"];
```

Comment: Assume nothing. OS X is a different beast entirely. If you come from iOS like I do, everything takes 100x longer, and you end up with 20 open browser tabs into Apple's Developer Library, trying to figure out how to accomplish a simple task...